# How would you eject an object from an airlock for maximum velocity?

Tags: spacecraft, eva, airlock, velocity

If a space explorer needed to eject an inert object from a cylindrical airlock that was roughly barrel shaped (length >> diameter) at maximum velocity, would they be better suited to position the object at either end or somewhere in the middle, before opening?

In the hopes of exposing the underlying physics, I propose to assume that the hatch is able to open pretty much instantaneously, but other considerations would be interesting.

Comment: You can be 100% sure that the airlock won't open until it has cycled all the air inside it. Opening vacuum onto vacuum, your position inside it will be irrelevant. Is this an actual space exploration question, or perhaps something more suited to worldbuilding stack exchange.

Comment: What does "either orifice or otherwise" mean? What orifices?

Comment: @Diego Sanchez - of course you are right, this would not be the normal operation of an airlock. Perhaps this is too hypothetical for SESE, but its not science fiction. Surely NASA looks at all sorts of uncontrolled decompression scenarios.

Comment: @Organic Marble - meaning at the inner or outer hatch of the airlock or somewhere in between. I revised the wording.

Comment: Such an explosive decompression from 1 bar down to vacuum would be dangerous for the space explorer. His space suit may burst and kill him. A rapid decompression from 1 bar airlock pressure down to about 0.3 bar suit pressure may cause decompression sickness.

Comment: I think that's what the science-based tag is for on worldbuilding @CrystallineEntity

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic - it should be on Worldbuilding - it doesn't work here because it is based on inaccurate assumptions around how airlocks work.

Comment: I tend to agree. This is a better question for [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think you just want to understand the physics of guns. You will notice that most guns are designed with the bullet in the back end, so that the bullet has the maximum amount of time to be accelerated by the expanding gas.

Answer (score 8):

You can't open an airlock hatch to vacuum until the pressure inside is essentially zero.  The hatch opens inward and is held closed by tons of force if there is any appreciable delta pressure.

Airlocks are designed for safety and reliability, not circus stunts.

Comment: I wonder if you could add to your answer. I modified the question to eliminate some implausibility. I assume that the decompression is similar to that of a bullet in a gun barrel and you would want the projectile to be nearer the outer hatch, in front of the expanding gas.